# Android Wallpaper Manager is merging images

Tags: android, wallpaper, homescreen

I have developed an android app in which I have implemented a background service using **AlarmManager**, which executes after every 20 seconds and change the home screen wallpaper of device, its working fine. But, there is an issue which is very frequent, the android **Wallpapermanager** mix up 2 images *(one is device default wallpaper)* and start showing the combination of 2 images on my home screen. if home screen wallpaper is set as scrolling wallpaper. [you can see in attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MScGI.png), which is very annoying. I have tried to fix this up, by increase service execution delay but all in vain. Will you please suggest me a suitable solution for this.  here is my code

```
 final WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    Bitmap bm = null;
    File imgFile = new File(imageURL);
    if(imgFile.exists()){
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    if(bm == null) return;

    try {
        myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bm);
        bm.recycle();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: We need to see the code

Comment: I have added code in my post will you please check.

Comment: try calling `myWallpaperManager.clear();` before setting bitmap, see what happens